# Setting mysql port number in agile toolkit

Tags: atk4

How do I set a port number for mysql connection in Agile Toolkit? The mysql in my local machine is running in a different port 3307, how should be my connection configuration look like?

I tried the following but it did not work,

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://atk:password@localhost:3307/atk';
```

I am getting the following error when I try a db test,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib\DBlite/mysql.php:40 [2] mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib\DBlite/mysql.php:40 [2] mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 

SQLException

Database connection failed

MySQL error: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 


C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib\BaseException.php:37

Stack trace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/BaseException.php :37  SQLException BaseException->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0) 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/SQLException.php :45  SQLException BaseException->__construct("<p>Database connection failed</p><b>MySQL error:</b> <div style='border: 1px solid black'><font color=red>No connection could be...", Null, 1) 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/DBlite.php :359  SQLException SQLException->__construct(Null, "Database connection failed") 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/DBlite.php :101  gift_project DBlite->fatal("Database connection failed", True) 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/ApiCLI.php :276  gift_project DBlite->connect(Array(7)) 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\page/dbtest.php :7  gift_project ApiCLI->dbConnect() 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/AbstractObject.php :129  gift_project_dbtest page_dbtest->init() 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/ApiFrontend.php :90  gift_project AbstractObject->add("page_dbtest", "dbtest", "Content") 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/ApiWeb.php :305  gift_project ApiFrontend->layout_Content() 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/ApiWeb.php :297  gift_project ApiWeb->addLayout("Content") 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2\atk4\lib/ApiWeb.php :182  gift_project ApiWeb->initLayout() 
C:\xampp\htdocs\atk4.1.2/index.php :15  gift_project ApiWeb->main()
```

***Solution : The following type of configuration works,***

```
$config['dsn']=array('type'=>'mysql',
             'hostspec'=>'localhost:3307',
             'username'=>'atk',
             'password'=>'password',
             'database'=>'atk',
             'charset'=>'utf-8');
```

Comment: I think it is a bug. I'll address it in the up-coming 4.1.3.

Meanwhile, have you tried to pass DSN in array format?

Comment: @romaninsh I am sorry, I did not try that. How do I do it?

Comment: It's mentioned here briefly: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/db

Comment: @romaninsh :( That does not seem to be working as well

Comment: @romaninsh It works now and I Have edited the post with the actual configuration that worked. I think the "type" was missing in the URL(http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/db). Thanks a bunch

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've also created bug report for the problem with DSN: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
 $config['dsn']=array('type'=>'mysql','username'=>'atk',
 'host'=>'localhost','database'=>'atk','password'=>'password',
 'port'=>3307,'charset'=>'utf-8');
```

Comment: Tried this, does not work. I have updated the post with the error I am getting

Comment: I got it working now. The configuration is added in the post. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Gald you got it working - i tried my suggested syntax with port 3306 and it works but i dont have access to a mysql with a different port number. Noted that in the original post you mentioned port 3307 but in your working version, you specify 1529 so assume you tried it with the correct port number.

Comment: Yes its kind of a different config for dev and test, the 3307 was my dev and the one was on the test :) the catch was that it is mix and match of what romaninsh and you told..Sorry that the port number was misleading Thanks again for your time...